# How to pass and retrieve constant JSON data from eventbridge rule to a lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I've an eventbridge rule defined and in the target I've configured a lambda function. I'm passing a constant JSON(configure target input) as following
[image]

Inside the lambda function what is the way to get the values defined in Target/Configure Input /Constant(Json text).

```
        public void EventHandler<T>(CloudWatchEvent<T> inputEvent, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            // Get constant json argument passed from event rule
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Haven't you asked already for that?

Comment: @Marcin Yes but still not able to find a solution. Will cancel the other one

Comment: Shouldn't it be in the inputEvenet?

Comment: @ErikAsplund In inputEvent it's coming null for me

Comment: I don't think so its doable, just add your inputs prams in Parameter Store if they are constant and fetch from there